# Generating invalid Vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, invalid-data

I need an invalid layer to test a plugin in QGIS. In the plugin window, I select a layer from combobox. So, the invalid layer should be in the `Layers` panel. I google for a while but I cannot find a way to generate an invalid vector layer.

How can I generate one so that `layer.isValid()` returns `False`?

Comment: Did you try self crossing lines, polygons? See also here (at the bottom of the paragraph): https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html#configuring-the-checks

Comment: @babel, Doesn't it create an invalid geometry instead of an invalid layer?

Comment: OK, you're probably right. Could you just create any kind of geopackage, than open it in a text editor, add or delete a few characters, thus making it invalid? Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @babel Thanks for the trick. This method genereate an invalid data. But in this case, I cannot add the data to Layers panel. I've added more information.

Comment: What if you first add it as a (valid) layer and only than change it outside of QGIS?

Comment: I tried it with a point layer. The points are still visible after the change in the layer outside of QGIS, but when I try to duplicate the layer, I get an error: `duplication resulted in invalid layer`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VmZF.png
However, I'm still able to successfully run simple tools with the original layer, like extract vertices of create buffer. So probably not yet the solution you look for, but maybe a direction that could lead to one?

Comment: Too add possible "invalidity" to the layer, I tried to add to the layer mentioned before a new field with the field calculator. When saving, all features disappear from the attribute table and the points are not shown any more in the map canvas. But I am still able to run buffer etc. without error message, however the output is empty.

What if your create a valid shapefile in QGIS and than remove/rename one of the mandatory sidecar files?

Comment: A good source of  "unusual" data can usually be found in the software tests (see the Github repo)

Comment: Reminds me of this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425991/add-vrt-via-pyqgis-not-working-whereas-same-file-loaded-via-the-gui-works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Providing an invalid path makes it invalid: `layer = QgsVectorLayer("zxcxzcxc/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")`
- Or a `providerlib` that doesnt exist: `layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks.shp", "testlayer_shp", "O G R")`, it should be `"ogr"`

Then add `layer` to the project:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using `QgsVectorLayer` without parameters generates an invalid vector layer.

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer()
print(layer)
# OUT:
# <QgsVectorLayer: '' (Invalid)>

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

[image]