# Add VRT via PyQGIS not working whereas same file loaded via the GUI works

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, vrt

How to reproduce my issue? Create the 2 files, a CSV and a VRT from below recipe (also available at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/56db21b335e25668ff86c2e8359bf3d1).

Then, try to add them with both GUI and PyQGIS.

Tested on QGIS 3.16 on my side on an Ubuntu 18.04

My `exemple-valide.csv` CSV content

```
id;longitude;latitude;famille_arbre;genre_arbre;espece_arbre;cultivar_variete_arbre;nom_vernaculaire;code_insee;code_postal;adresse;matricule_arbre;date_plantation;hauteur;diametre;type_sol;type_enracinement;port_arbre;arbre_remarquable;arbre_protege;contraintes_sol;contrainte_aeriennes;eclairage;arrosage;allergie;remarque
1;49.802;0.3768;Sapindaceae;Acer;campestre;;Erable champetre;13028;13600;320 Avenue Joseph Roumanille;259001;2018-05-12;100;58;Argilo-sableux;Oblique;Boule;Non;Non;Sol perméabilisé;Cables éléctriques;Oui;Goutte à goutte;3;
2;43.2959;5.3761;Rosaceae;Pyrus;calleryana;chanticleerc;"Poirier ""chanticleerc""";13055;13001;60 rue sainte;1998PyrCal130011150;1998-04-20;235;73;Argileux;Pivotant;;Non;Non;Grille abimée;proximité d'un mur;Non;;;tronc abimé lors de travaux
3;43.2915;5.4805;Platanaceae;Platanus;occidentalis;;Platane d'Amérique;13055;13002;72 Boulevard des Dames;;1990-03-01;;;;;;Non;Non;;;Oui;;2;dans un alignement
4;44.2920;5.3705;Pinaceae;Pinus;sylvestris;;Pin sylvestre;13055;13013;48 rue des hauts bois;;;;;Sableux;Pivotant;Cône;Oui;Non;;;;;;
```

My `exemple-valide.vrt` file

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="exemple-valide">
    <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1" shared="1">exemple-valide.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>exemple-valide</SrcLayer>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="longitude" y="latitude"/>
    <Field name="id" type="Integer" src="id"/>
    <Field name="longitude" type="Real" src="longitude"/>
    <Field name="latitude" type="Real" src="latitude"/>
    <Field name="famille_arbre" type="String" src="famille_arbre"/>
    <Field name="genre_arbre" type="String" src="genre_arbre"/>
    <Field name="espece_arbre" type="String" src="espece_arbre"/>
    <Field name="cultivar_variete_arbre" type="String" src="cultivar_variete_arbre"/>
    <Field name="nom_vernaculaire" type="String" src="nom_vernaculaire"/>
    <Field name="code_insee" type="String" src="code_insee"/>
    <Field name="code_postal" type="String" src="code_postal"/>
    <Field name="adresse" type="String" src="adresse"/>
    <Field name="matricule_arbre" type="String" src="matricule_arbre"/>
    <Field name="date_plantation" type="Date" src="date_plantation"/>
    <Field name="hauteur" type="Real" src="hauteur"/>
    <Field name="diametre" type="Real" src="diametre"/>
    <Field name="type_sol" type="String" src="type_sol"/>
    <Field name="type_enracinement" type="String" src="type_enracinement"/>
    <Field name="port_arbre" type="String" src="port_arbre"/>
    <Field name="arbre_remarquable" type="String" src="arbre_remarquable"/>
    <Field name="arbre_protege" type="String" src="arbre_protege"/>
    <Field name="contraintes_sol" type="String" src="contraintes_sol"/>
    <Field name="contrainte_aeriennes" type="String" src="contrainte_aeriennes"/>
    <Field name="eclairage" type="String" src="eclairage"/>
    <Field name="arrosage" type="String" src="arrosage"/>
    <Field name="allergie" type="Integer" src="allergie"/>
    <Field name="remarque" type="String" src="remarque"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Both VRT and CSV files are in the same directory

When I load the VRT manually via the GUI, it displays correctly whereas I do it using the following, it does not

```py
vrt_dest_path = 'myabsolutepath_to_exemple-valide.vrt'
uri_vrt = f"{vrt_dest_path}|layername='exemple-valide'"
vectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri_vrt, layername, "ogr")
project.addMapLayer(vectorLayer)
```

**What do I miss that make things failed with PyQGIS? Something obvious?**

I've made some assumptions/deductions below but without findind out where is my issue...

From what I see, it seems related to QGIS through the GUI detecting the block content

```
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="longitude" y="latitude"/>
```

whereas within PyQGIS it does not. I suppose this also because of differences between QGIS file qgs content part for both `<maplayer>` blocks e.g

XML excerpt from qgs file when added via GUI https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/56db21b335e25668ff86c2e8359bf3d1#file-maplayer_gui-xml

vs

XML excerpt from qgs file when added via PyQGIS where you can notice a `geometry="Unknown geometry"` https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/56db21b335e25668ff86c2e8359bf3d1#file-maplayer_pyqgis-xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to remove the quotation mark around the `layername` argument in the url.

Following script should do the trick:

```py
vrt_dest_path = 'D:\Downloads\exemple-valide.vrt'
uri_vrt = f"{vrt_dest_path}|layername=exemple-valide"
vectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri_vrt, 'Test', "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer)
```

Comment: Indeed it does @_@ so simple

Comment: More details here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

Comment: Surprising. If I do select a valid layer and execute `iface.activeLayer().source()`, it returns `'/home/thomasg/exemple-valide.vrt|layername=exemple-valide'` whereas if I do `iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().uri().uri()`, it returns `" /home/thomasg/exemple-valide.vrt|layername='exemple-valide'"` It was the cause of my syntax with single quote that failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I could get the same error `"Unavailable layer!"` as you on my QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich.

[image: error]

Unfortunatelly, until now I can not find out the reason for your problem.

However, I can offer several solutions.

You can try this:

```py
from qgis.core import *

vrt_path = "D:/TESTING/exemple-valide.vrt"
vrt_info = QFileInfo(vrt_path)
vrt_name = vrt_info.baseName()

vrt_layer = QgsVectorLayer(vrt_path, vrt_name, "ogr")

if not vrt_layer.isValid():
    print (f'{vrt_layer} is not valid!')
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vrt_layer)
```

As an alternative, there is ["Create points layer from table"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-points-layer-from-table) algorithm available under `"qgis:createpointslayerfromtable"` in PyQGIS

```py
import processing

vrt_dest_path = "D:/TESTING/exemple-valide.vrt"

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:createpointslayerfromtable",
    {'INPUT' : vrt_dest_path,
    'MFIELD' : '', 
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
    'XFIELD' : 'longitude',
    'YFIELD' : 'latitude',
    'ZFIELD' : ''})
```

Both pieces of code end up in:

[image: reuslt]

Comment: See my comment on other answer to understand where the issue was from. Your answer with only vrt path alone is also fine as long as there is only one layer. I had to make a choice to acknowledge one of the two answers as both are fine.